# atomエディタが複数開いてしまう件

Tags: atom-editor

atomエディタが新規でアプリを起動したと同時にのウィンドウが毎回出てきてしまいます。

少しうざいので、解決したいです。

どなたか解決方法知っている方いらっしゃいs

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、この記事が該当するでしょう。
[How to open a new file in a another tab instead of a new window in Atom editor?](https://superuser.com/q/1389397)
質問

> 私はすでに自分のLinuxでアトムエディタウィンドウを開いていて、ターミナルから他のファイルを開くためにアトムを実行してみます。
>
> ```
> atom /path/to/new_file.txt
> ```
>
> 新しいファイルを開くときに、現在開いているアトムエディタで新しいタブを開く代わりにatomが新しいウィンドウを開こうとします。アトムウィンドウがすでに開いている場合に、（configなどを介して）アトムに新しいウィンドウを開かないように指示する方法はありますか？

回答

> **新しいウィンドウを開かないように（configや何かを通して）atomに伝える方法はありますか？**
>
> ```
> atom -n false /path/to/new_file.txt
> ```
>
> どこで：
>
> ```
> -n, --new-window Open a new window. [boolean]
> ```
>
> ソース：[Open file/project from terminal / command line - features - Atom Discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/open-file-project-from-terminal-command-line/1305/9)
>
> ```
> atom --help
> Atom Editor v0.80.0
>
> Usage: atom [options] [file …]
>
> Options:
> -d, --dev Run in development mode. [boolean]
> -f, --foreground Keep the browser process in the foreground. [boolean]
> -h, --help Print this usage message. [boolean]
> -l, --log-file Log all output to file. [string]
> -n, --new-window Open a new window. [boolean]
> -s, --spec-directory Set the spec directory (default: Atom’s spec directory). [string]
> -t, --test Run the specified specs and exit with error code on failures. [boolean]
> -v, --version Print the version. [boolean]
> -w, --wait Wait for window to be closed before returning. [boolean]
> ```

---

> **atomにはrcファイルやグローバル設定があるので、このオプションをデフォルトとして設定できますか？**
>
> Atom `config.cson`は、`%USERPROFILE%\.atom`ディレクトリー内のファイルから構成設定をロードします。
>
> ただし、この`--new-window`オプションは構成可能なオプションの1つではありません。
>
> ソース：[Basic Customization](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/)